# Nginx express static files not found

Tags: file, express, nginx, static

I am trying to serve static contents with nginx instead of express.

Nginx server block static file part is

```
location / {
    root /var/www/analytics/web/static;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @analytics_web;
    expires off;
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
}
```

The static resources are in `/var/www/analytics/web/static` and they get served if i include `app.use('/static', express.static(app.get('config').paths.static));` in express setup.

Any ideas where i am going wrong.

Full nginx [conf](https://gist.github.com/swarajgiri/8d0b9767aacbf24ca0ba)

Comment: Can you show the output of `/var/log/nginx/error.log` (last few lines after attempting to access the page)

Comment: Also, why do you have two `location /` blocks? You should consolidate your code into one. Its possible you are overwriting the first one with the second one.

Comment: Lastly, if that doesn't make an immediate difference, try putting a trailing slash on the `root` command (once you combine the two `location /` blocks), like so: `root /var/www/analytics/web/static/;`

Comment: @AllTheTime - No errors in the log. Tried with trailing slash on root. Still not working. Any ideas how i should merge the 2 `locations` blocks

Comment: Trailing slash isn't going to do anything when you're overwriting the first location block. Just put all the code that's in both location blocks in one location block.

Comment: Nope. Still nothing in error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

The location block for static files needs to be something like

```
location ~ ^/(assets/|images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
    root /var/www/analytics/web/;
    access_log off;
    expires 24h;
}
```

Comment: Yeah makes sense. I think Its because the proxy pass in `location /` to your express server was overriding any static file serving that would have been done. By using a separate location for static files this conflict goes away.